# How do i read my data through reader?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to read from datareader but i am gettin the error "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed." The stored procedure is working fine but when i try to read fom datareader it throws error.Plz help me

```
protected void CheckDatabase()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        conn.Open();
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];
        param[0]= new SqlParameter("@EmpID", SqlDbType.Int);
        param[0].Value = txtEmpId.Text;
        param[1]= new SqlParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.VarChar,50);
        param[1].Value = txtDate.Text;
        SqlDataReader reader = DNDatabase.ExecuteStoredProcedureReader("RetrieveDeatails", param);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            gridConfirm.DataSource = reader;
            gridConfirm.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            gridConfirm.DataBind();
                Session["Task_List"] = reader;

        }}
```

here is stored Procedure code

```
public static SqlDataReader ExecuteStoredProcedureReader(string procedureName, SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {

        SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection(DNDatabase.SQLConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, _conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = procedureName;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
        try
        {

            foreach (SqlParameter param in parameters)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            }
            _conn.Open();

            return cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        }
        catch (Exception sqlExc)
        {
            throw new Exception("An error occured", sqlExc);
        }
       finally
        {
            if (_conn != null)
                _conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what DNDatabase.ExecuteStoredProcedureReader looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bad idea to me:

```
Session["Task_List"] = reader;
```

You execute that and *then* call `reader.Read()` again, continuing until there's nothing left to read. Presumably you also close the reader at some point (I'd hope - ideally with a `using` statement). Fundamentally, a `SqlDataReader` is a *connected* resource - it's like a stream to the database. It's not something you should be holding onto for longer than you need to, and it's *certainly* not something you should be putting in a session, even if you didn't effectively invalidate it with the subsequent `Read()` call.

I assume that data binding works by fetching the data when you call `DataBind()`, but there's no indication of what you're trying to achieve by putting a reference to the reader itself into the session.

I suggest that:

- You isolate whether this is actually to do with the session or the databinding
- If it's the session, you pull all of the data you need out (e.g. into a `DataTable` or some other "disconnected" form)
- If it's the databinding, you'll need to do something similar - but as I say, you can *hope* that that's not the problem, to start with - I assume you saw this sort of databinding elsewhere?

Additionally, you should consider why you want to loop - currently you're basically going to loop over all the results and only the *last* one is going to be displayed (because you're overwriting the databinding each time). Is that really what you want?

Comment: I also tried after removing session from there but got the same problem..I just wanted databinding and then i needed the data retrievd some where else...............

Comment: @mona: So you need to actually *fetch* the data from the `SqlDataReader` into whatever form you wanted. I suggest you load it into a strongly-typed object or collection, then bind to that and put that object in the session or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

check DNDatabase.ExecuteStoredProcedureReader code may it close the reader after fetchdata 
and another thing i should say is:
you can'nt use  Session["Task_List"] = reader; because reader is forwardonly 
and if you want to keep current value of reader in a seesion load in data table and keep data row of table

DataTable dt = new DataTanle();
dt.Load(dr);
and loop over data table rows

Answer (score 0):

Your method ExecuteStoredProcedureReader has a finally statement which closes the connection. Hence you cannot read anything from the reader. Either close the reader in your method where you call ExecuteStoredProcedureReader or merge both the methods to have them in a single method.